# DXL Import via Java doesn't work with 8.5.2

Tags: java, import, xpages, lotus-domino

I have another problem with a DXL Import, in fact it's the same class from my old question (http://goo.gl/LchgP)

Everything works fine, as long as you are on a Domino 8.5.3 Server. With 8.5.2 it won't work. I receive the following error message:

```
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM: NotesException: DXLImporter output object is invalid, uninitialized, or not explicitly declared and strongly typed
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at lotus.domino.local.DxlImporter.importDxl(Unknown Source)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at biz.bcc.common.BCCPropertyStore.importDXLFile(BCCPropertyStore.java:514)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at biz.bcc.common.BCCPropertyStore.saveProperties(BCCPropertyStore.java:777)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:220)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:365)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1490)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:206)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:193)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:86)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:538)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1140)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:803)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:758)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:527)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1124)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:513)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:342)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:304)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:261)
07.02.2013 14:45:06   HTTP JVM:     at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:291)
```

The code didn't change since the last question.

Do you have any idea why it should work on mylocal server 8.5.3 on a virtual machine and on our other server with 8.5.2 it won't work?

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not much to go on there without a small sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Line 514 is "importer.importDxl(stream.readText(), db);"

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using the getCurrentSessionAsSignerWithFullAccess  method. This is , as far as I know, an extension library method. Be sure you installed the extlib on both servers. In 8.5.3 there could be the upgrade pack installed which automatically means you have the extension library. On 8.5.2. you have to install it manually.

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not the case. We have copied the code from the extension library source into our class to get the sessionAsSigner. That's all standard domino code which should be supported by 8.5.2.